# Get value from bootstrap data-toggle="button" on click

Tags: jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble getting the value of the selected radio button with a bootstrap button group

```
<form action="cart.php" method="post" id="addtocart">
    <div id="select1" class="product-options " data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="radio" name="option1" value="1"> 1 </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="radio" name="option1" value="2"> 2 </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="radio" name="option1" value="3"> 3 </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Upon a selection being made, I need to get the selected value. I understand I should be able to get the value like so:

```
$("#select1").click(function() {
    var option1 = $("#select1 label.active input").val();
});
```

or alternatively

```
$("#select1").click(function() {
    var option1 = $("#select1 input:radio:checked").val();
});
```

However both variants on first click return "undefinied" and on second click return the value that was selected "before". How can I get the selected value on first click?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to hook to the `change` event of the radio itself instead of the `click` of the parent `div`. Try this:

```
$("#select1 input:radio").change(function() {
    var optionValue = $(this).val();
    console.log(optionValue);
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/phg1vp7t/)

Answer (score 0):

Selected value can be obtained by: 
`$("#select1 input:radio:checked").first().val();`

Note the `.first()` addition.